# Zurb Foundation Slider only use step value when dragging

Tags: slider, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I have a foundation slider value that is also bound to a number input.

The number input needs to allow for any value to be in place but the slider can only increment in steps of 1000. The problem is if the number input has a specific number the slider overrides the input value leading to inaccurate results. The slider must be in setps of 1000 if the cost is approximate.

```
       <input type="text" name="cost-box" id="cost-box" class="">
    
      <div class="slider cost-slider" data-slider data-step="1000" data-start="30000" data-initial-start="{{ $someValue }}" data-end="900000">
      <span class="slider-handle"  data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1" aria-controls="cost-box"></span>
      <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
```